# attach event to objects in array

Tags: jquery

I'm working on creating a sidebar that contains color swatches that, when clicked, fill a form with those colors. Its for a Wordpress theme.

Each of the color swatches is an object contained in an array. I use an .each() function over the array to create the HTML for each swatch, but I also need to create a way so that when a swatch is clicked, the color fields fill with that swatch's colors.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccnokes/6emfD/
*there are more comments in the code that clarify what I'm talking about.

As you can tell from the fiddle, each swatch only fills the fields with the last swatch's colors. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorganize it a little bit so that you are attaching the click event to each anchor tag as it is created rather than after.

http://jsfiddle.net/6emfD/2/

```
//Color Swatches JS
//color swatch array containing objects that contain the target fields and colors
var swatches = [
    $fuego = {
    name: 'fuego',
    primary_color: '#c0342a',
    primary_hover_color: '#a0140a',
    primary_hover_color_2: '#800000',
    secondary_color: '#ff7600',
    secondary_hover_color: '#df5600',
    secondary_hover_color_2: '#bf3600',
    tertiary_color: '#ffd005',
    tertiary_color2: '#ffd409',
    h1_color: '#c0342a',
    h2_color: '#a0140a',
    background_color: '#ffd005'},
    $veggies = {
    name: 'veggies',
    primary_color: '#5f8a42',
    primary_hover_color: '#86ad59',
    primary_hover_color_2: '#f6faa1',
    secondary_color: '#f28410',
    secondary_hover_color: '#d66011',
    secondary_hover_color_2: '#b24400',
    tertiary_color: '#a44a0e',
    tertiary_color2: '#a84e0f',
    background_color: '#a44a0e'},
    $jazz = {
    name: 'jazz',
    primary_color: '#3b2e8c',
    primary_hover_color: '#022859',
    primary_hover_color_2: '#023059',
    secondary_color: '#6cafd9',
    secondary_hover_color: '#4c8fb9',
    secondary_hover_color_2: '#2c6f99',
    tertiary_color: '#ffffff',
    tertiary_color2: '#fcfcfc',
    background_color: '#ffffff'}
];

//Create color swatches HTML
$(swatches).each(function() {
    var $swatch = this;
    $('<a id="' + this.name + '"><ul class="swatch"><li class="main" style="background-color:' + this.primary_color + '"></li><li style="background-color:' + this.primary_hover_color + '"></li><li style="background-color:' + this.primary_hover_color_2 + '"></li><li class="main" style="background-color:' + this.secondary_color + '"></li><li style="background-color:' + this.secondary_hover_color + '"></li><li style="background-color:' + this.secondary_hover_color_2 + '"></li></ul></a>').on('click', function() {
        fillSwatches($swatch);
        console.log($swatch);
    }).appendTo('.swatch-wrap');

});

//on swatch click, fill fields with corresponding colors    


function fillSwatches($swatch) {
    $.each($swatch, function($key, $value) {
        fillColor($key, $value);
    });
}

//fill color scheme


function fillColor($field, $color) {
    $('#' + $field).val($color).css("background-color", $color).change();
}

/*the following function works but can't it be abstracted so that every swatch doesn't have to be written out in this format? */

/*
$('#fuego').on( 'click', function(){
   fillSwatches($fuego);
});
*/​
```

Comment: Works great, thanks Kevin. I figured the answer was simpler than I was making it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

Add a swatch data-attr to each `<a>` and then do something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var swatch = swatches[$(this).data('swatch')];  
    fillSwatches(swatch);
});
```